# displaying a background image in a Java Swing application

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I read several answers on my topic but I have not found my answer.
I would like a background for my java code.
I refer here only to put the code for the image
but it does not work.

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class background extends JFrame {
    private Container c;
    private JPanel imagePanel;

    public background() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        c = getContentPane();
        imagePanel = new JPanel() {
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                try {
                    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("http://www.signe-zodiaque.com/images/signes/balance.jpg"));
                    g.drawImage(image, 1000, 2000, null);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        imagePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        c.add(imagePanel);
    }
```

Comment: *"it does not work"*  Maybe it is on strike, or sleepy, or just plain lazy.  For the first, negotiate.  For the second, give it a good night's rest and try it in the morning.  For the 3rd, try the carrot & stick approach.  For anything else, try describing 1) What you expected to happen 2) What actually happened, and for utility 3) Why you expected (1) to happen.

Answer (score 6):

Where did you find that code? If from a tutorial, please discard it as it's teaching you very bad habits. For instance,...

- You *never* want to read in an image file (or any file) from within a `paint(...)` or `paintComponent(...)` method. For one, why make the program re-read in a file each time it is re-drawn when you could read it in once and be done with it. But even more importantly, you want your paint/paintComponent methods to be lean, mean and as fast as possible, because if not and your drawing is slow and klunky, the user will perceive your program to be slow and klunky.
- Do your drawing in a JPanel's `paintComponent(...)` method, not its `paint(...)` method. When you draw in paint you lose all double buffering that Swing offers for free and your animations will be jerky.
- Call the super's `paintComponent(...)` method first.
- Read the official [Painting with Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) on how to do graphics and drawing in Swing, as I'm guessing from the code above that you haven't yet done this most basic step. You won't regret doing this.
- Also you appear to be trying to load a url as a file which I don't believe will work. Use a URL object instead.

For example...

```
public class ZodiacImage extends JPanel {
   private static final String IMG_PATH = "http://www.signe-zodiaque.com/" +
        "images/signes/balance.jpg";
   private BufferedImage image;

   public ZodiacImage() {
      // either read in your image here using a ImageIO.read(URL)
      // and place it into the image variable, or else
      // create a constructor that accepts an Image parameter.
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (image != null) {
         // draw your image here. 
      }
   }

   @Override  //if you want the size to match the images
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (image != null) {
         return new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
      }
      return super.getPreferredSize();
   }
}
```

Comment: Added to which `g.drawImage(image, 1000, 2000, null);` is almost as silly. Those co-ords would be off my physical screen, and the container should be used as the `ImageObserver`.  Then there is overriding `paint()` in a Swing panel, extending a Swing frame (seemingly) unnecessarily, trying to load an application resource as a `File`..  That code probably has more errors than lines.

Comment: @leen.zd: `"always we use this method"` is not a good reason for using it, unless by "we" you mean Joshua Bloch or James Gosling. When you draw in paint you lose all double buffering that Swing offers for free and your animations will be jerky. Also, `"but it doesn't work"` doesn't tell us much. How doesn't it work? What doesn't work? Any errors? C'mon, give the important details.

Comment: @leen: Also you're trying to load a web resource as a file, see edit.

Comment: *"web resource"*  Seems a confusing term to me.  It implies an applet.  I use the words 'application resource', though I'm not sure that indicates to the listener that the resource is 'part of the application'.  I wish there were a more common and standard term.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes,  you're probably correct. I want to say that he's trying to load an URL as a File but it's not, it should be created via `new URL(urlString)`

Comment: @leen.zd: please let us know what happens, if it works, or especially if the re-write doesn't. If the latter occurs, edit your original post with your new code and then add a comment to my answer.